# Approximation by "odd" fractions

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Are there any results about approximating irrational numbers by fractions in which the numerator and denominator are both odd? [The question arose in looking for whether $\liminf_{n\to\infty}n\cos n = 0$. The corresponding result for $n\sin n$ comes from rational approximation of $\pi$. But the question for $n\cos n$ seems intrinsically harder, and appears to need some additional tool.]

Comment: Do you mean $n|\cos n|$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes! I believe that the lim inf is 0, but I have still not seen a proof .

Answer (score 0):

Both limits have no inf (I mean liminf = - infinity) just as limsup is + infinity

Indeed even for positive integers as
$$-1\leq \cos n \leq +1 \longrightarrow -n\leq n\cos n\leq +n$$
and as $n\to +\infty$ the set of limit values is dense in $(-\infty,\;+\infty)$

Same for sin

Hope this helps

A graph for $n\cos n$ from $10^{10}$ to $10^{10}+500$

[image]

Comment: I overlooked that! What I actually want to know is if $1/(n\cos n)$ goes to zero.

Comment: @ChrisL Yes it does, but is a completely different sequence. As $\cos n$ stays bounded in $[-1;\;1]$ denominator goes to $\infty$ and the fraction goes to zero

Comment: But $\cos n$ can get very small. If it is ever as small as $1/n$ then $n\cos n$ will not be going to $\infty$.

Comment: Indeed my answer says that there is no limit since the value of $n\cos n$ bounces between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. I add a graph to my answer for some values after $n=10^{10}$

Comment: @ChrisL:  Yes, $\cos n$ can be small, but it is large often enough that $n \cos n$ can get very large.  When you are looking for divergence because of "bouncing around", like here, the terms need to be large infinitely often, not all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. What I really want to know is how to prove the assertion that "as $n\to+\infty$ the set of limit values is dense in $(-\infty,+\infty)$". In particular, why is $0$ in that limit set?

Comment: It is not! But for any $\epsilon>0$ it can be found $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|n \cos n|<\epsilon$. And this for any  $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$